# CSS3. JS. Анимация header c абсолютного на фиксированный

Tags: javascript, html, css3, анимация, css-animation

Я верстаю тестовый макет и решил сделать плавный переход у `.header`, c `positon: absolute` на `position: fixed`.
Я прочитал в интернете, что можно анимировать исчезания элемента, который оставляет за собой место c помощью `visibility: visible` + `opacity: 0`, а на конец анимации `visibility: hidden` + `opacity: 0` 
Я сделал анимацию, c `absolute` анимация появления происходит плавно при появлении, т.е. переход с absolute на `fixed` произошёл хорошо, но обратно у меня не получается. Я пытался что-то делать, но получалось плохо и криво. Я не понимаю, как это реализовать без костылей.
https://mihinov.github.io/ — тут можно посмотреть кривую анимацию
JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    var posY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
    var header = document.querySelector('.header');
    var height__intro = intro.offsetHeight; // высота intro
    if (posY+1 >= height__intro) { // если posY+1 > высоты intro, то появится header
        header.classList.add('fixed');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: auto;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    animation-name: header__visible;
}

@keyframes header__visible{
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;

    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Я пытался добавлять новый класс, у которого была своя анимация исчезания и убирать `.fixed`. Он шёл с 

0% `position: fixed`,`opacity: 1`, `background-color: black` `visibility: visible`

до 99% `visibility: hidden`, `opacity: 0`,
 а на 100% `position: absolute`, но на половине анимации происходил резкий рывок.

Как написать так, чтобы всё происходило плавно?

UPD: Вот код, при которым header на половине пути резко исчезает

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: auto;
    animation: 1s linear;
}

.header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    animation-name: header__visible;
}

.header.unvisible {
    animation-name: header__unvisible;
}

@keyframes header__visible {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;

    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes header__unvisible {
    0% {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: black;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    99% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    var posY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
    var header = document.querySelector('.header');
    var height__intro = intro.offsetHeight; // высота intro
    if (posY+1 >= height__intro) { // если posY+1 > высоты intro, то появится header
        header.classList.add('fixed');
        header.classList.remove('unvisible');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('fixed');
        header.classList.add('unvisible');
    }
});
```

Вот как это работает: 
Я думаю, что у меня не работает, из-за того, что я js'ом убираю какое-то важное свойство css

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.ele');
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
 ele.classList.toggle('comeOn');
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.ele {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   animation: 5s forwards;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.ele:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

.comeOn {
 animation-name: comeOn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
   }
 100% {
    visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     background-color: #ff6699;
   }
}

@keyframes comeOn {
 0% {
  visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     background-color: #ff6699;
   }
 100% {
    visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
     background: transparent;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="ele"></div>
```

Comment: Свойства `visibility` и `position` не аниммируются.

Comment: Что значит плавно?

Comment: @Gonzo я добавил анимацию исчезания, которуя я описывал, при пролистывании выше inner, происходит анимация и резко исчезает, я не понимаю почему

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko visibility в значениях visible и hidden вместе с opacity дают анимацию исчезания элемента, на который нельзя кликнуть(после исчезания) и как либо взаимдоействовать, но элемент оставляет за собой место

Comment: Исчезает резко, потому что `visibility` не анимируется. Вот он был `visible`, а потом резко стал `hidden`. Что бы нельзя было кликнуть - используйте `pointer-events:none`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я попробывал сделать тоже самое, но вообще без visibility, но всё равно исчезание на половине обрывается

Comment: Значит, добавляйте воспроизводимый пример кода, на котором бы можно было увидеть данное поведение.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил

Comment: В вашем снипете в хроме 77 анимация работает плавно, резких изменений не замечано.

Comment: А у вас на сайте он похоже не исчезает, а просто перемещается резко наверх, потому что меняется `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто попробывал анимации задать конечный пунт на 50%, где происходит исчезание, а на 100% `position: absolute`. Это как-то работает, не пойму как, правда.
UPD: Я протестировал, и оказывается это просто происходит намного быстрее и плохо заметно неплавное исчезание и это неполное решение проблемы

```
@keyframes header__unvisible {
    0% {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: black;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```